# How do I change the highlighted background of timepicker?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timepicker

I'm using timepicker control from [WPF Extended Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

This seems like a simple question, but I can't figure out how to do this no matter where I search.

How do I change the foreground/background color of a highlighted timepicker? I figured you'd need to use style triggers to do this but I don't know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seeing is default highlight colour of your system. To change it, you should override `HighlightBrushKey`.

Put this resource in `TimePickerControl` resources to change the highlight colour to `Red`:

```
<TimePicker.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="Red"/>
</TimePicker.Resources>
```